# How to import libraries into Groovy scriptler scripts?

Tags: jenkins-scriptler

I would like to import a 3rd party library that is not packaged with jenkins into a Scriptler script.  What do I need to do to make the packages within the jar available to jenkins?  Do I need to add the jar to the CLASSPATH - or some other way - so they are importable when I need them?  But How?!